# Removing specific index with user inputC#

Tags: if-statement, input, while-loop

I'm trying to make input from users specify what index should be removed from a list.

They get a list with ID on the objects then type in the ID for the object they wan't to remove. The written ID begins at 1 but is actually 0; so when users type 1 it will be changed to 0.

I've also made it so they can't choose an input outside the range of the index. I had it working for while but then i wanted to unallow whitespace input from users and that's where i did something wrong with my code.

I've reverted it to the point before i started editing it but i can't seem to find what's wrong!

```
public static void menuLISTA()
    {
        menuTEXT.WriteFullLine("-Din Digitalgarderobs innehåll-");
        Console.WriteLine("===============================================================");
        if (newklädDataList.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Din digitalgarderob är tom!");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("===============================================================");
            Console.WriteLine("Tryck [Enter] för att fortsätta."); Console.ReadKey();
        }           
        else if (newklädDataList.Count != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < newklädDataList.Count; i++)
            {
                klädDATALIST plagg = newklädDataList[i];
                Console.WriteLine("ID: {4}\tMärke: {0}\tTyp: {1}\tFärg: {2}\tStorlek: {3}", plagg.märke, plagg.typ, plagg.färg, plagg.storlek, i + 1);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("===============================================================");
            Console.WriteLine("Vill du ta bort ett klädesplagg? - Ange siffra -");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

                int svar = int.Parse(input);              
                int svarID = svar - 1;
                if (svar != 0 && svar < newklädDataList.Count)
                {
                    newklädDataList.RemoveAt(svarID);

                }
                else if (svar == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nVänligen ange ett giltigt plagg-ID. Tryck [Enter] för att fortsätta.");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.Clear();
                    menuLISTA();
                }

                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nVänligen ange ett giltigt plagg-ID. Tryck [Enter] för att fortsätta.");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.Clear();
                    menuLISTA();
                }


        }

        Console.Clear();
        menuTITEL.menuKläd();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

```
else if (newklädDataList.Count != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < newklädDataList.Count; i++)
            {
                klädDATALIST plagg = newklädDataList[i];
                Console.WriteLine("ID: {4}\tMärke: {0}\tTyp: {1}\tFärg: {2}\tStorlek: {3}", plagg.märke, plagg.typ, plagg.färg, plagg.storlek, i + 1);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("===============================================================");
            Console.WriteLine("Vill du ta bort ett klädesplagg? - Ange siffra -");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

                int svar = int.Parse(input);              
                int svarID = svar - 1;
                if (svarID == 0 || svar < newklädDataList.Count+1)
                {
                    newklädDataList.RemoveAt(svarID);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.Clear();
                    menuLISTA();

                }
                else if (svar == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nVänligen ange ett giltigt plagg-ID. Tryck [Enter] för att fortsätta.");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.Clear();
                    menuLISTA();
                }

                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nVänligen ange ett giltigt plagg-ID. Tryck [Enter] för att fortsätta.");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.Clear();
                    menuLISTA();
                }


        }

        Console.Clear();
        menuTITEL.menuKläd();
```